# java arraylist null pointer exception when adding

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, new-operator, local-variables

Could someone please help me understand why i'm getting a null pointer when adding to my array list. Im trying to make it so that it will change the text on a button when it is clicked, however my `ArrayList` does not seem to be adding the things into it?

```
public class Game {

private GUI gui;
private ArrayList<String> pairs;
boolean clicked; 

public Game() {
    gui = new GUI(this);
    clicked = false; 
    ArrayList<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>();

}

public void addPairs() {
    pairs.add("dog"); // where i get the null pointer
    pairs.add("dog");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the class field `pairs` in your `Game` constructor. Change

```
ArrayList<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**or** with the diamond operator like

```
pairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the class member `pairs`

```
this.pairs = new ArrayList<>(); // this may be omitted
```

instead of creating a new local list

```
ArrayList<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
```